# How to retrieve the old value of a column in a table after an update laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm wondering if this is possible.In my project user can  update a column value of a table.But other users cant see the updated value upto 14 days.Upto 14 days old value will populate in every retrival operations.Is it possible to do in laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either use caching or add another column on the table called `old_column`, then in your `Model` you could include a getter/accessor to check the `updated_at` timestamp on the row then either return the new/old value.

```
    public function getColumnAttribute($value)
    {
        if($this->updated_at < Carbon::now()->subWeeks(2)) {
            return $this->old_column;
        }
        return $value;
    }
```

be aware that since you have not been clear on your column names, I've literally named them:

`column` and `old_column`, the function name on your model should be `get{COLUMN NAME}Attribute`

See: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Note, if you want the user that edited the value to see the change, you must include `user_id` on the table. But at this point, you would not retain ownership of a change and would be better of making a `diff` style table to house all of these changes as a log.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to do it, you need to store both values.
Take the example of `price` column.
We can define **[accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)** in model

Have two columns `price` & `old_price`

```
public function getPriceAttribute($value)
{
    if($this->updated_at < Carbon::now()->subWeeks(2)) { // 14 days check
        return $this->old_price;
    }
    return $value;
}
```

And then you can user it as

```
$product->price;
```